# Java - How to allow all methods of a class to access an array initialized in constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, constructor

I'm interested in knowing how I can declare and initialize an array of JButtons in a class so that the constructor and methods of that same class will all have access to this array.

Currently, I declared the JButtons and array at the start of my class definition and initialized the array in the class constructor. However, this does not allow the rest of the class' methods to access the array's variables.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class demo{
    public JButton one;
    public JButton two;
    public JButton three;

    public JButton demoArray[] = new JButton[3];

    public demo(){
         demoArray[0] = one;
         demoArray[1] = two;
         demoArray[2] = three;
         ....
         }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {...
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
             demoArray[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Uh, put the reference for the array in the class as an instance field, perhaps?

Comment: Post your code, as your question stands we cannot help.

Comment: Static field maybe, or global one in class?

Comment: Are you actually creating any `JButton` objects at all?  Or are you getting a `NullPointerException` when you try to use them, because they don't exist yet?

Comment: I left out that bit of code, but no, I do create the JButtons in my full code. 
Thanks though :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as access goes, this should work. You should be getting an error when actionPerformed is called, because you try and access demoArray[3], but it only goes from 0 to 2.

Here is some working code, taken from your own. There are a few changes, which I've commented.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

// Extend JPanel so we can put the buttons somewhere
// Implement ActionListener so we can listen to them
public class Demo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public JButton one;
    public JButton two;
    public JButton three;

    // This holds the same objects as above. You don't need both.
    public JButton demoArray[] = new JButton[3];

    // This is used to show the results
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create our Demo
        Demo demo = new Demo();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.add(demo);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Using uppercase for Class name and lower case for objects
    public Demo() {

        super();

        // Create our buttons            
        one = new JButton("one");
        two = new JButton("two");
        three = new JButton("three");

        // Put them in the array.
        // We could have just created them in the array directly.
        demoArray[0] = one;
        demoArray[1] = two;
        demoArray[2] = three;

        // Put the buttons inside this (the JPanel)
        // and listen to them
        for (JButton button : demoArray) {
            add(button);
            button.addActionListener(this);
        }
    }

    // What to do when we hear them
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // There are only three buttons, not four
        // That is, demoArray[0], demoArray[1], 
        // and demoArray[2]
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            demoArray[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought too.. but it doesn't.
When actionPerformed is called, the code before it runs as expected, but the JButtons aren't disabled as they should be.

I can't figure out why as it compiles fine as well.
The only reason I could imagine is because I initialized my array in a constructor making it local to the constructor

My question is this: is there anyway to initialize an array outside a constructor? 

NetBeans doesn't seem to allow me to

Comment: I've added working code (and tested). The buttons are disabled as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this!
I've looked over my code and compared it with your solution here.

What I did wrong was I assigned a position in the JButton array to a JButton without first having intializing it to a JButton (I initialized it after)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. You can do it in one step, cutting out the individual buttons and just using the array. I'm typing this on my phone, so forgive mistakes, but something like : JButton[]  buttons = new JButton [3]; for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {buttons[i]  = new JButton("Some text") ;... Allocate listener and so on...}

Answer (score 1):

A variable declared in the class scope and initialising in the constructor should be accessible everywhere within the class.

as in:

```
private/public <Class> <object>;
```

should be sufficient, will need to see some code if you require further assistance.

[edit]
What you posted should work fine, but before you do

```
demoArray[0] = one;
demoArray[1] = two;
demoArray[2] = three;
```

you should declare them. i.e

```
one = new JButton();.......
```

Otherwise you will get a nullPointerException.
as far as accessibility goes, you should be ok with what you have.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new to Stack and was having a bit of trouble figuring out how to post my code